# How NOT to break a function/loop on returning a value (Js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

Hey so I am making a 2D tile game, or really I am just messing around. I have made the map from an array, where 0 represents nothing, and other characters represents a walkable tile.

```
var map=[["t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t"],
    ["l","1","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","r"],
    ["l","r","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","r"],
    ["l","1","t","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","l","r"],
    ["l","1","1","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","t","r","0","0","l","r"],
    ["l","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","1","1","b","b","b","b","b","t","t","b","r"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","l","r","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","l","r","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","l","r","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","l","1","1","r","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","l","1","1","1","1","r","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["t","t","t","t","t","t","t","1","1","1","1","1","1","t","t","t","t","t","t","t"]];
```

[On screen it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVEdS.png)

You see my moveable character here as well.
Now I have come this far, and I'd like my character to collide with the empty tiles represented as the value of 0 in my map array.

This is my code for checking collision (brackets are correct in the script):

```
function collisioncheck(ind){
for(var i in map){
    for(var j in map[i]){
        if(yass==true){
            if(map[i][j]==0){
                if(ind==0 && playerPosX==j*32+32 && playerPosY>i*32-32 && playerPosY<i*32+32){
                    return false;
                }else if(ind==1 && playerPosX==j*32-32 && playerPosY>i*32-32 && playerPosY<i*32+32){
                    return false;
                }else if(ind==2 && playerPosY==i*32+32 && playerPosX>j*32-32 && playerPosX<j*32+32){
                    return false;
                }else if(ind==3 && playerPosY==i*32-32 && playerPosX>j*32-32 && playerPosX<j*32+32){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
var yass=false;
function exist(){
for(var i in map){
    for( var j in map[i]){
        if(map[i][j]==0){
            yass=true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, this works. But only for the first 0 in the map. My problem is that the return statements breaks the for-loop and function. So my character will not collide with any other blank tile but the first one.

I will have to rewrite this, but is there any smart solution to this?

[Link to jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0q3dynfc/) (Character not visible)

Comment: you can `break label;` or `continue` instead of using `return`, where `label` is a label on a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, your loop only runs for one iteration because you always return something after an iteration. However, you should only call return when you know the final result, because - as you said - it will exit the function.

It is correct to call 'return false' right away after a collision is detected, because if the player collides with at least one block, then there is a collision. On the opposite, 'return true' should only be called when you are sure that there are no collisions at all on the entire board, and you need to test every block on the map before you can confirm this.

```
function collisioncheck(ind) {
    for (var i in map) {
        for (var j in map[i]) {
            if (yass == true) {
                if (map[i][j] == 0) {
                    if (ind == 0 && playerPosX == j * 32 + 32 && playerPosY > i * 32 - 32 && playerPosY < i * 32 + 32) {
                      return false;
                    } else if (ind == 1 && playerPosX == j * 32 - 32 && playerPosY > i * 32 - 32 && playerPosY < i * 32 + 32) {
                      return false;
                    } else if (ind == 2 && playerPosY == i * 32 + 32 && playerPosX > j * 32 - 32 && playerPosX < j * 32 + 32) {
                      return false;
                    } else if (ind == 3 && playerPosY == i * 32 - 32 && playerPosX > j * 32 - 32 && playerPosX < j * 32 + 32) {
                      return false;
                    } 
                    // else: do nothing. (i.e. let the loop run for the next block)
                }
            } else {
              return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

What we do here is go through all the blocks, if we find a collision we return false and exit the function. We only reach the 'return true' statement if we went through all the blocks without finding any collision, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! Your answer really makes a lot of sense, and it works ;))

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `continue` instead of `return` in the last else of your main if/else block on line 15